# as3 get URLLoader's `data` property before the `COMPLETE` event?

Tags: actionscript-3, download, urlloader

Adobe says `This property is populated only when the load operation is complete`.

Is there any (I mean really any) way to get the downloading data while it's in downloading state? 
In the `onprogress` event, for example.

Probably there is another way to download the file and get the data before downloading is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible but with [`URLStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) rather than `URLLoader`. You can take a look at [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html#includeExamplesSummary) on live docs.